# Find number in Young tableau in $O(n+m)$

Tags: algorithms, young-tableaux

Give an $O(n+m)$-time algorithm to determine whether a given number is stored in a given $m\times n$ Young tableau. An $m\times n$ Young tableau is an $m\times n$ matrix such that the entries of each row are in sorted order from left to right and the entries of each column are in sorted order from top to bottom. Task has got simple solution (I saw answers after my algorithm), but I made my own. I am not sure about its time complexify.

**Algorithm**: Let $x$ - required number. Assume we have matrix $A$ $n\times n$ (if not we can split matrix). If $x > A[n][n]$ or $x < A[1][1]$ return false. If not, we can find with binary search $k: A[k][k]=x$ (return true) or $i,j: A[i][i]< x < A[j][j]$. Since tableau is Young, $A[j\dots n,j\dots n]>x $ and $A[1\dots i,1\dots i] < x$ so $x \notin A[j\dots n,j\dots n]$ and x $\notin A[1\dots i,1\dots i]$. Then we have two another matrixes with smaller size where $x$ may be: $A[1\dots  i ,j\dots n]$, $A[j\dots n,1\dots j]$.  $i^2+j^2$ (elements of throw matrixes) > $i*j + j*i$ (elements of new matrixes), so $T(n)<= 2T(n/2) + \theta(\lg n)$

**I tried**: At each recurrence step in the worst case (number not exist in matrix and two split points in the middle at each iteration) we have two matrixes to solve with size ~$n/2$. We also made binary search with diagonal elements so $T(n)=2T(n/2) + \theta(\lg n)$. By master theorem $T(n)= \theta(n)$. 
If split points not central then

So $T(n) = O(n)$ in base case.

**Question**:Is my analysis wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your recursion may end up finding one extreme corner of the matrix as the "split" point and then your algorithm will be $\Theta((m+n) \log(m+n))$. The traditional approach to this problem to get your desired complexity is to test, say, an upper-left  corner where everything to the right of the corner in the row is greater than, and everything below the corner in the column is less than. Then you either find your desired number at the corner, or you eliminate either one row or one column from the search. By continuing this way always testing corners, at most you have to test $m + n$ corners before all rows and columns are eliminated (in which case, your number is not in the table). So complexity is $O(m + n)$.

Comment: But if its found extreme corner, then it will has only two lines of matrix and in this case may be solved by binary search? Yes, right solution like yours (lower-left, you mean?)

Comment: You right, it behave like $O(n\lg n)$. With matrix $3000 \times 2000$ in worst case it runs with $4195000 $ nanoseconds. In clean $O(n\lg n)$ case $1580000$ nanosec and $2002$ nanosec in your case with $O(n)$.

Comment: @slmkarta Yes it may be lower left corner to test (or opposite corner), you just want that all entries in the row/column (starting at the corner) are increasing along one axis and decreasing along the other axis (or vice versa). That's what guarantees the $O(m + n)$ running time.

Comment: Thank for responding. I want to find fail in my time-complexity analysis. I posted larger question on SE CS http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45402/find-number-in-young-tableau-in-onm with my attemps of analysis. I really not understand you first sentence.

Comment: I also think that running-time settlements in this post more correct than before.

Comment: @slmkarta I looked at your CS.stackexchange post & I think you should actually post your question on StackOverflow, and include your code for your original "recurse on submatrices" approach (not "clean" binary search one column at a time), so that people can look at your code and tell you what may be causing the huge difference between running times of your original approach and the "clean" $O(n \log m)$ approach that searches each column individually. People are willing to look at code on StackOverflow, and are willing to help with these kinds of questions that CS.SE might find "too simple."

Comment: I posted question on SO (without concrete realization) and then get down by users and migrated on CS (moderator advice). In my implementation i used arrays of indexes (left-upper and right-lower angles of matrix)  so this is not clear readable code.

Comment: @slmkarta It seems they are down-voting you too on CS.SE (hence why I recommended SO, because SO usually likes somewhat not-too-hard questions that have not-too-hard code to read). If CS.SE and SO are BOTH not liking your questions, then I'm not sure what to do. I recommended SO because I suspected maybe there is some coding detail causing the big difference in running time between your approach and "clean $O(n \log m)$ approach".

Comment: I will try to post on SO.  My analysis seems right? If we don't see concrete realization with splitting and submatrices?

Comment: @slmkarta I'm not sure if your approach will give $O((m+n) \log(m+n))$ performance always. I only know that is the case if you find an upper-right or lower-left corner as your split entry during your binary search. It seems if you test "center entry" $A(n/2,n/2)$ and recurse based on the comparison to $x$, then you will get $T(n) = 3 T(n/2) + O(1)$ for the running time, which would solve to something worse than $O(n \log n)$. If you recurse on something besides the "center" using your approach, other than the off-diagonal corners, I don't see how it can be better if you use the diagonal.

Comment: @user256092 Add some information. Maybe there is a problem that  $T(n)<= 2T(n/2) + \theta(\lg n)$ assumption based on amount of elements is wrong.